# Visual HG add shortcut to commit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, keyboard-shortcuts, visualhg

Is there a way I can create a keyboard shortcutto to a commit in Visual Studio 2010? I am using Visual HG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using VisualHG v1.1.4 the keyboard shortcut command name is `File.Commit`

Answer (score 1):

You can add one by going to `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`. Then search for `commit` and select the command that says `Mercurial.Commit` (or something similar).

**Update:** I installed VisualHG but there is no option to customize (and add shortcut to commit). I guess this makes it a feature request!

You can probably install other Mercurial SCC package that lets you customize it.